# Running one task in an SSIS package

Tags: ssis, sql-server-data-tools

I've got an SSIS package that copies data from a mainframe to a SQL Server table, runs a stored procedure to massage the data, and then export the contents of a final table to a text file.

My question is; how can I test the export step?  I'm new to using SSIS, I'm using SQL Server Data Tools 2015.  I've read that you click on the Debug menu item and Start Debug, but for whatever reason (IT restrictions in my company?) the Start Debugging menu option is grayed out.

Comment: Running it as Debug (or hitting F5) is how I test/validate SSIS packages locally before deploying them.  If your company does not allow that then you would have to create a job to execute the package and run it from there with whatever test you need (destination paths to a test location, etc).  It is more time consuming but the only way I can see to do it if you are not allowed to just debug.

Comment: Could you confirm that IT disabled debugging in Visual Studio?  That's a pretty indefensible position - like saying a plumber can't use a wrench.  I wonder, if instead, there's something wrong with your install of visual studio or the SSIS extension

Comment: Have you created an SSIS project and include this package in that project and 'set as the 'start-up object'? If the package was created elsewhere (using the data import/export wizard, for example) Visual Studio will still allow you open/view and edit, but it wouldn't know what to debug without a project.

Comment: @tinazmu - That might be it, because it's not visible as a project so I open it as a file.  I'm brand new to SSIS and this package was developed by someone on our IT team who handles the running of them.  I'll try recreating it as a project and see if that enables the Debug function.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, I'll go ahead and answer this.  The cause was that the SSIS package I designed was created as a *File*, and not a *Package*.  When all the objects were copied into a new Package, the ability to run in Debug mode for any step in the Package was made available via the Debug menu, or by right-clicking on the step and choosing "Execute Task".